# Image does not appear

Tags: bug, images

At least for me and some other users an image that did not appear in my answer in [Why the $\nabla f(x)$ in the direction orthogonal to $f(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401845/why-the-nabla-fx-in-the-direction-orthogonal-to-fx/402080#402080). What could it be?

**Update** for some reason I can already see the picture in my answer.

Comment: I can see your nice image, how did it?

Comment: @GastónBurrull  I used the vector drawing software Inkscape (free) with a plugin that allows me to write the text boxes in LaTeX for Linux does not need the plugin. To install the plugin on Windows see this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61274/is-there-any-way-to-type-latex-code-directly-into-the-text-boxes-inkscape

Comment: Output is fantastic.